# Stopwatch repeating time one after another with pause between

Tags: java, android

this is my first time writing here. I am learning Android development and trying to make a stopwatch (countdown timer) app, which has 12 rounds and pause - example 10 sec between them. I wrote a code which works fine but I want to write it more "readable and nicely" so I would like to ask you for your help. As you can see, I don't want to write every time under `public void run()` in if-else if statement new roundtime number and setting text because it would take too much space. That is why I wrote it just for example(not 12 times) so you can see what I mean. Do you have any suggestions how to write it better for 12 rounds? Can I use a loop? If u have easier way for countdown round after round I would appreciate it. I am sorry for my english. Any comments are welcome. Enjoy coding.

This is my code:

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Handler handler;
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView2;
    ImageView imageView3;
    Boolean checker=false;
    long secondtime=1000;
    long roundtime1= 10000;
    long roundtime2=10000;
    long pause= 31000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        imageView2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        imageView2.setOnClickListener(
                new ImageView.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        handler = new Handler();

                        if (checker == false) {
                            handler.post(r);
                            checker = true;
                        }
                        imageView3.setOnClickListener(
                                new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
                                    }
                                }
                        );
                    }
                        final Runnable r= new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                roundtime = roundtime - secondtime;
                                int seconds = (int) (roundtime / 1000);
                                int minutes = seconds / 60;
                                seconds = seconds % 60;
                                if (roundtime >= 0) {
                                    textView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

                                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
                                } else if (pause > 0) {

                                    pause = pause - secondtime;

                                    int secondss = (int) (pause / 1000);
                                    int minutess = secondss / 60;
                                    secondss = secondss % 60;

                                    textView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutess, secondss));

                                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
                                } else if (roundtime2 > 0) {
                                    roundtime2 = roundtime2 - secondtime;
                                    int secondsss = (int) (roundtime2 / 1000);
                                    int minutesss = secondsss / 60;
                                    secondsss = secondsss % 60;
                                    textView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutesss, secondsss));

                                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
                                }else{
                                    textView.setText("Over");
                                }

                            }
                        };
                    }
        );




    }
}
```

Comment: Try shorter question next time. While yours is answered, take a couple of minutes to see others' questions as an inspiration.

Comment: u can implement Onclick to your activity to avoid such nesting

Comment: Thanx YSC,will try nex time.

Comment: Rachit Solanki,will try and respond. Thanx

Comment: I've used [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) for similar purposes, but I did not need repetition. Check it out, and try to think of the way to repeat it twelve times. I'd try with some kind of a while loop which creates new Class which contains the timer on previous timer's `onFinish()` method. Basic idea only.